# Python :- How to store query result data into an array and access each element by Index number

Tags: python, oracle

I want to store data in a array variable say path_list and to store all the states into this array.
And when i print path_list [0] it should print 'MSF' 
or when i print path_list [2] it should print 'MIF'
But currently all the result is getting stored into a tuple and it is not getting printed when i use print in the for loop.
However, when i printing it outside of loop it is working. Please suggest me any way

My table structure is like

```
STATE    TOC      ID      NUMBER
MSF   MSPROFMSV 465984  5926987700
MSF   MSPROFMSV 465977  5926063400
MIF   MIPROFMSV 465977  5926063100
MIF   MIPROFMSV 465977  5926063900
```

Code:-

```
import cx_Oracle
import shutil
import os
import logging
import time
import re
timestr = '_'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")    
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'lsaxena2/Dec2*19k@ed03:1521/encdv03svc.uhc.com') 
cur_path = conn.cursor()
cur_file = conn.cursor()
cur_path.execute('select distinct state from E0572476.ENSUBAPP_config order by state') 
path_exec = cur_path.fetchall()
i=0
path_list = []
print (path_exec[1][0])
while i < len(path_exec):
   path_list = path_exec[i][0]
   print (path_list[i])    
   i = i+ 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL generates rows, which are always tuples. Since cr.fetchall fetches all results, you're getting a list of rows = a list of tuples. Even if you only have one value, it's a 1-uple.

So you just need to extract the one value from your tuple and move it to the output list:

```
path_list = [row[0] for row in path_exec]
```

Incidentally your naming scheme is awful. And I don't understand why you have two cursors, or why you never close them

```py
import cx_Oracle
import time

timestr = '_'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

with cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'lsaxena2/Dec2*19k@ed03:1521/encdv03svc.uhc.com') as conn,\
     conn.cursor() as cr:
    cr.execute('select distinct state from E0572476.ENSUBAPP_config order by state') 
    states = [state for [state] in cr.fetchall()]
```

Comment: The naming scheme is not the actual scheme i used in the code.
It's just a template of that so never mind that